# How to remove the date from the log file name in log4net

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

The log file i wanted is just "Log.txt.0" and I don't want the date to be appended to the log file. Even after not adding the date pattern I am getting the date appended to the log file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
</configSections>
<log4net>
    <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <!-- Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number -->
            <conversionPattern value="%5level [%thread] (%file:%line) - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
        <!-- Log files are logged in the AppData path for Traylogs.log -->
        <file value="${APPDATA}\Project\Application\My Application\Logs.txt"/>
        <staticLogFileName value="false" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <countDirection value="1"/>
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">            
            <conversionPattern value="%level %thread %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
</log4net>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings />
    <client />
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

How can I remove this date that is appended to the log file?

Comment: Could you show us part of log file (with dates)?

Comment: @llya - Logs.txt.2014-06-11.0 - this one. And also how I have set the log file size to 100KB and after the log file exceeds this value, it is not able to create one more log file. It is logging to the same file. No new file is created

Comment: I am able to remove the date from the log file. After adding this <rollingStyle value="Size" /> it eliminated the date from the log file

Comment: I.e. the problem is not inside log file. The problem is in name of log file. It is better to add this specification to question!

Comment: Default value of `countDirection` is `–1`. It means, that newest logfile backup will always be "YourLogName.1" (i.e. it adds number 1 after log file name). Read about default values to avoid such problems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default we have `datePattern = ".yyyy-MM-dd"` (so you have this postfix). So, if you don't need date in log file name, you can set `<datePattern value="" />` (empty string instead of default value).